# Converting UNIX time from Android JSON feed

Tags: android, eclipse, json, unix, datetime

I know similar questions have been asked, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.  I've added the code I am using to call the JSON feed and display it in a ListAdapter.  I need to get my fields "ShowDate" and "ShowStart" to display in a readable format, not UNIX.

```
public class Schedule extends ListActivity {
protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected TextView textView;
protected ImageView imageView;
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.gradiant);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {
                    0xFF95B9C7, 0xFF06357A });
    gd.setCornerRadius(2f);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

    myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("MyAPIURL");


        JSONArray current = json.getJSONArray("d");

        for (int i = 0; i < current.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = current.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("showid", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ShowID")));
            map.put("name", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Title")));
            map.put("showvenue", "" + e.getString("ShowVenue"));
            map.put("subtutle", "" + e.getString("SubTitle"));
            map.put("venueid", "" + e.getString("VenueID"));
            map.put("showdate", "" + e.getString("ShowDate"));
            map.put("showstart", "" + e.getString("ShowStart"));
            map.put("showend", "" + e.getString("ShowEnd"));
            map.put("image250", "" + e.getString("Image250"));
            map.put("aboutartist", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("AboutArtist")));


            myList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

    }



    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,R.layout.line_item, 
            new String[] { "name", "showdate","showstart", "showvenue", "image250" }, 
            new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.showdate,R.id.showstart,R.id.showvenue, R.id.list_image });


    setListAdapter(adapter);



    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = myList.get(position);
            // hashMap.put("map", hashMap);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ArtistDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
}
```

Any suggestions or advice will be greatly appreciated.  I've spent way too much time on this for something I assume is fairly simple.  Thanks!

Comment: So is your problem with the JSON, the connection, or converting a Unix timestamp into a readable date? If it is the last one, just use a Date constructor that takes in a timestamp, and pass it to a SimpleDateFormat to format it the way you want. Otherwise, please narrow down what the problem is.

Comment: It is the converting Unix to a readable date.  Would the Date constructor go inside the onCreate?

Comment: Date d = new Date(timestamp); String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss").format(d); You can find what each letter means in the format by following the link in one of the posted answers.

Comment: I appreciate the help so far.  Thank you all.  hopefully last question before this works.  I am getting an error on (timestamp).  Do i need to define(protect) that in some way?  Or is that where I should be adding my "showdate"?

Comment: timestamp is whatever variable you have defined that is storing the timestamp. ex: long timestamp = 3928385743; //Except that number would be from your JSON feed.

Comment: I'm still struggling on this.  when i place "Date F = new Date("showdate"); String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss").format(F);" above my onCreate, my activity crashes.  Suggestions? (srry, this is my first app using json, and only my 3rd app that is getting released. I know I'm strugging with some simple concepts here :-) )

Comment: Can you open a new question and post the code/stack trace? Stack Overflow is angry that there are so many comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640063/android-json-time-conversion-from-unix/9640132#9640132

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the replies.  Turns out that this is all I need it to do.  It may just be a quick fix, but it works.  I needed to put it inside my JSONArray.

```
String showDate = e.getString("ShowDate");
long epoch = Long.parseLong( showDate );
Date showDatePresent = new Date( epoch * 1000 );
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMMM d");
String dateOfShow = sdf.format(showDatePresent);
map.put("showdate", "" + dateOfShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked out the SimpleDateFormat object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to `parse` the date you're given and then to `format` the way you want it

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, to convert a timestamp to a date you use `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
Date d = new Date(timestamp);
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss").format(d);
```

But it seems like you don't know where to put it. You will need to set a `ViewBinder` in your `SimpleAdapter` object that will display the date in the format you want.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,R.layout.line_item,
        new String[] { "name", "showdate","showstart", "showvenue", "image250" },
        new int[] { R.id.title, R.id.showdate, R.id.showstart, R.id.showvenue, R.id.list_image });

adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex("showdate")
                || columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex("showstart")) {
            Date d = new Date(cursor.getLong(columnIndex));
            String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss").format(d);
            ((TextView) view).setText(formattedDate);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```